# How to communicate between scripts in Unity (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bomberman game in unity. I have an error when resupplying bombs to the player once they have exploded. There is a player script and a bomb script. When the bomb explodes, I want to to increment the players bomb counter in the player script, but this gives me a null reference exception.

```
public class Bomb : MonoBehaviour {
public AudioClip explosionSound;
public GameObject explosionPrefab; 
public LayerMask levelMask; // This LayerMask makes sure the rays cast to check for free spaces only hits the blocks in the level
private bool exploded = false;
public Player _Player;//link to player
// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    Invoke("Explode", 3f); //Call Explode in 3 seconds
}

    if (exploded == true)
    {
        if (this.name == "Player 1's bomb(Clone)")
        {
            _Player.bombsP1 += 1;
        }

        else if (this.name == "Player 2's bomb(Clone)")
        {
            _Player.bombsP2 += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a _lot_ of options here. You can expose a field on your script where the user can drag an in the editor. You can use the field to access scripts, etc on the object. You can also find an object reference using `GameObject.Find()` (although if you use this method, search once and save the result, it can be expensive). You can also use the Singleton pattern (Google it). Unity has a messaging API that allows scripts to send broadcasts / notifications and listen for events. Personally, I go for one script that holds references to everything else, and use it like a signpost.

Comment: Did you assign the reference to the `_Player` field of the `Bomb` object in the editor?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, I click the player field on the bomb script but I dont know what to put there. There are no suggestions to fill the player fields in the editor.

Comment: from the  editor - click on the bomb, then click and drag the player player to the _Player field on the inspector. This will tell the Bomb which Player instance to refer to. @Programmer this is not a duplicate as my answer isn't on the link you put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just work with tags :P So maybe it'll be easier and Set player to "GameObject" and drag and drop it in the Inspector